# sprintf undefined behavior

Tags: c++, printf

Definitions and declarations:

```cpp
char *PassengerList[3];
PassengerList[0] = PassengerList[1] = PassengerList[2] = "";
```

This bit of code illustrates my issue. Printing cid gives my expected value, while later referencing the names in PassengerList gives blanks, and occasionally the expected value.

```cpp
char cid[5];
sprintf( cid, "c%d", id );
//char out[512];
//sprintf( out, "%s", cid );
write( 1, cid, strlen(cid));
PassengerList[PassengerCount] = cid;
```

However, If I uncomment those two lines and comment out the write call:

```cpp
char cid[5];
sprintf( cid, "c%d", id );
char out[512]; // using a size of 10 here also causes mumbo-jumbo
sprintf( out, "%s", cid );
//write( 1, cid, strlen(cid));
PassengerList[PassengerCount] = cid;
```

I end up getting all the expected values correctly every time. Any idea why putting the value of cid in another string and ignoring it makes it then store correctly?

Using PassengerList later:

```cpp
void BoatMonitor::BoatReady( char* id1, char* id2, char* id3 )
{
    // other stuff
    sprintf( id1, "%s", PassengerList[0]);
    sprintf( id2, "%s", PassengerList[1]);
    sprintf( id3, "%s", PassengerList[2]);
    // other stuff
}

// other file
static BoatMonitor BoatM("BoatM");

void Boat::ThreadFunc() {
    // other stuff
    char id1[5];
    char id2[5];
    char id3[5];
    BoatM.BoatReady( id1, id2, id3 );
    
    outMutex.Wait();
    sprintf( out, "***** Boat load (%d): Passenger list (%s, %s, %s)\n", tripCount, id1, id2, id3 );
    write( 1, out, strlen( out ) );
    outMutex.Signal();
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: getting unexpected output is not automatically undefined behavior. If you knew that the code has undefined beahvior, you would actually know already what is wrong

Comment: What's the value of `id`?  You're likely just going out of bounds in your array.  Run with something like asan enabled and you'll probably find the error quickly.

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` ? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: I think the problem is here: `PassengerList[PassengerCount] = cid;` isn't cid some local variable `char cid[5];`

Comment: Use [snprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) in C, and `std::string` or `std::ostringstream` in C++

Comment: @drescherjm it is a local variable, should I be using strcpy or something instead of normal assignment as I'm doing here?

Comment: @StephenNewell id is an integer less than 30, so I dont think it would be. I think 4 is the max including a null terminator, but I made it 5 just to be safe.

Comment: `PassengerList[PassengerCount] = cid` is storing a pointer to the array `cid`.  No problem because the array `cid` exists.  But if `cid` then goes out of scope or gets reused for another passenger, **you are left with a dangling pointer**.  You need a new string for each passenger... in C that would be `strdup()`/`free()` and in C++ use `std::string`.

Comment: @zq_Aux *However, If I uncomment those two lines and comment out the write call:* -- And if you compiled with different compiler settings, you may find some other behavior.  So the question is -- is it worth all of this effort to figure out a moving target such as undefined behavior?

Comment: @BenVoigt Alright, so if I change PassengerList to a std::string array of size 3, then I can assign as normally, and change the input parameters of the function to std::string pointers instead of char pointers?

Comment: @zq_Aux Don't use pointers to std::string. They are input parameters and not written to so use `const std::string&` as the type. Or if you use C++17 you might use `std::string_view`

Comment: @zq_Aux Oh I didn't understand. Those *are* output parameters. I would prefer returning an object instead but if you must, then yes use pointers or references to std::string.

Comment: @ZanLynx oh, my bad. Output parameters, then. I've always gotten those mixed up. I'll try returning a std::string array then

Comment: @zq_Aux: In some sense all parameters are inputs to the function... but that sense is covered just by saying "parameter".  When the whole purpose of a parameter is to identify an object (or array of objects) which is to be completely overwritten in the function, that's when we say "out parameter".  We really mean "output buffer parameter".  And if we identify an object (or array) which has a meaningful value on entry to the function and also is mutated by the function in a way that's interesting to the caller, that's an "in/out parameter".